# Странное поведение push

Tags: javascript

```
var cells = [];
cells.push(new CellModel({gid: -200}));

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "xml",
    url: "/utils/tilemap.tmx",
    success: function(data){
        $(data).find("tile").each(function(){
            var g = $(this).attr('gid');
            cells.push(new CellModel({gid: g}));
        });
    }
});

cells.push(new CellModel({gid: -400}));
cells.forEach(function(g){
    //Somecode
});
```

Этот код запрашивает с сервера xml и парсит ее, создавая модели с прочитанным параметром gid и добавляя их в массив cells. Но почему-то внутри цикла each() push ведет себя очень странно. Он срабатывает без ошибок, но при этом в массиве не появляется добавленных им элементов. Мало того, он возвращает правильный размер массива (увеличивая на 1 на каждой итерации).

Push до и после запроса с циклом добавляют все адекватно, их значения потом можно узнать в forEach, в отличии от значений, добавляемых внутри цикла. Переменная g тоже определяется правильно.

В чем может быть проблема, почему метод push для массива cells не добавляет элементы в массив, но при этом еще и увеличивает его размер, как будто добавил?

Comment: Это не проблема Push.Скорее всего вы не учитываете то факт, что ajax запрос будет выполнен после функции foreach, т.к. он будет ожидать результата выполнения запроса по указанному адресу, а следующий за ним foreach будет выполнен сразу.

Comment: @Ruslan, откуда тогда там увеличение количества элементов в массиве?

Comment: Как я сейчас выяснил, если выводить весь массив внутри запроса, то в нем все что нужно добавлено. Но вне запроса он никак не меняется.

Comment: По поводу того, к каком порядке будет что выполняться - этот массив, когда он полностью сформируется, дальше по коду выводится на экран (к этому моменту он уже заполнится). И даже при том выводе он выведет только два элемента: -200, -400.

Comment: @Visman автор пишет про кол-во элементов которое выдает цикл внутри функции Success, а не про кол-во которое выводит функция foreach.

Comment: Хотя действительно, сперва отрабатывает то, что после запроса, а только потом запрос завершается. Как с этим можно бороться?

Comment: @АндрейКурулёв коллбеки или промисы: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/

Comment: @АндрейКурулёв Два варианта либо вызывать то что у вас ниже ajax отдельной функцией внутри success функции ajax, или, я это категорически не рекомендую, сделать ajax синхронным с помощью параметра `async: false`

Comment: Спасибо, действительно помогло. Если не сложно, оформите этот комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы другим было искать проще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как мне подсказали в комментариях, "ajax запрос будет выполнен после функции foreach, т.к. он будет ожидать результата выполнения запроса по указанному адресу, а следующий за ним foreach будет выполнен сразу" "Два варианта либо вызывать то что у вас ниже ajax отдельной функцией внутри success функции ajax, или, я это категорически не рекомендую, сделать ajax синхронным с помощью параметра `async: false`" © Ruslan